# Prove that R (upper triangular matrix) is invertible in QR factorization (decomposition)

Tags: linear-algebra

In the question it is stated that the rank of an $n\times n$ matrix $A = QR$ is $n$. So knowing this, how am I suppose to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $A$ is $n\times n$. So, $A$ is full rank, i.e. invertible. Now, we have that $Q$ is orthogonal, so that it is also invertible, since $Q^TQ=QQ^T=I_n$. If $R$ were not invertible, then $QR$ would not be invertible, so that $QR\ne A$.